# Rails / Ajax - update action for comments partial not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building an events app using Rails 5.0 and have comments as a nested resource. Users can create and destroy comments, I'm trying to implement the edit/update function using Ajax/ remote: true so they can update a comment on the same page but it's not working. When I click on the edit link nothing happens. Here's the relevant code -

**comments_controller.rb**

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController


before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to @event
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end


# GET /comments/1/edit
def edit
    @event = @comment.event
    @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.js {}
    end

end

def show
end



def update 
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Comment was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

    respond_to do |f|
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: "Comment Successfully updated!" }
        format.js # render 'comments/update.js.erb'
    end

end



def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to event_path(@event)


end

private

def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
end
```

end

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <div id="comments" class="comment">  
      <p id="comment_name"><strong><%= @comment.name %></strong></p>
      <p id="comment_body"><%= @comment.body %></p>

  </div>

      <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_comment_path(comment.event), id: "comments", remote: true %></p>

                  <p><%= link_to 'Delete', comment.event,
                                     method: :delete,
                                        class: "button",
                              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update.js.erb**

```
$('#comments').append("<%= j render @comment %>");
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#comments').html("<%= j render 'form' %>");
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I've never implemented this action before using Ajax so I'm probably making a few schoolboy errors here. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: You are not rendering anything in edit action...So nothing is happening...

Comment: Do you have form to update the comment when the edit link is clicked?

Comment: @Pavan Do you want me to add the form?

Comment: Your `edit` action looks odd, you have a circular reference there: `@comment` is needed to set `@event`, and `@event` is needed to set `@comment`. Aren't you getting any error with `@comment.event`?

Comment: @Gerry No nothing, I think this may be a routing issue but I can't quite understand where its going wrong.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Forget my comment, i missed your `set_comment` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling edit method on controller with this

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.event, comment], id: "comment", remote: true %>
```

And you have no **edit.js.erb**

For updating your comment, you would have to create a form with it's action url pointing to your update method, and marking it as remote true. Then when you submit, it will reach update directly, there is no need to pass through edit method.

There is a method for creating forms with ajax option as default called form_with, you can check it's guide and documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with

**Updating answer after your question update**

Your form would need to become something like this

```
<%= simple_form_for :comment, :url => "/events/#{comment.event_id}/comments/#{comment.id}", :method => :put do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I want to be able to edit a comment but I wasn't sure whether the actual actions need to be performed by update as the edit function just loads the edit page.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead ok updating my answer

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead there  you go

Comment: Can I still use this method if I'm using simple_form ?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead if "this method" is my solution, yes you can use, there is no "form-with" in simple form, there you will need to pass `remote: true`, like you did for you link_to

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead an example `simple_form_for @company, :url => {:controller => 'companies', :action => 'update_company', :remote => true }, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'company_name' }  do |f|`

Comment: Ah, I see. I've just updated the question with the form now included and as you can see mine does not look like yours.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead that was just an example. What you are missing here is action method. Your form like it was was calling for get method

Comment: No, there's still nothing happening. There must be something fundamental I'm getting wrong on this, just can't see what.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I'm not liking the way you are constructing your url, could you run "rake routes" and find the route to where you want and construct it with a helper?

Comment: These are the routes - edit_event_comment GET      /events/:event_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
                   event_comment GET      /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                                 PATCH    /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                                 PUT      /events/:event_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update

Comment: 'Undefined method comment in Events#show' - pointing to the simple_form_for line of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147273/discussion-between-ramon-marques-and-mike-whitehead).